# How to get JS OTEL auto-instrumentation packages compatible with Yarn 2?

Tags: node.js, yarn-v2, otel

We are trying to use `@opentelemetry/*` packages with our project that also uses `Yarn@3.6.3` and the `pnp` functionality (no `node_modules` directory). Our issue is described in the related https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/1412

The errors we are getting in our spans are similar to:

```
  ...
  status: {
    message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/node_modules/graphql/index'",
    code: 2
  },
  events: [
    {
      name: 'exception',
      attributes: {
        'exception.type': 'ENOENT',
        'exception.message': "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/node_modules/graphql/index'",
        'exception.stacktrace': "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/node_modules/graphql/index'\n" +
          '    at makeError$1 (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:15833:24)\n' +
          '    at ENOENT (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:15848:10)\n' +
          '    at ZipFS.statSync (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:17272:13)\n' +
          '    at /<proj>/.pnp.cjs:18572:20\n' +
          '    at /<proj>/.pnp.cjs:19026:60\n' +
          '    at ZipOpenFS.getZipSync (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:19155:14)\n' +
          '    at ZipOpenFS.makeCallSync (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:19026:17)\n' +
          '    at ZipOpenFS.statSync (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:18569:17)\n' +
          '    at VirtualFS.statSync (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:18041:24)\n' +
          '    at PosixFS.statSync (/<proj>/.pnp.cjs:18041:24)'
      }
    }
  ],
```

We have localized these error spans to the auto-instrumented `@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fs` package (as when we disable that package we do not get there errors).

It has been recommended to use `packageExtensions` to handle the dependency issue here, but how do we orient the correct extension?

The latest we have tried is:

```
# .yarnrc.yml

packageExtensions:
  '@opentelemetry/sdk-node@^0.44.0':
    dependencies:
      '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fs': '^0.8.3'
  '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fs@^0.8.3':
    dependencies:
      'graphql': ^16.8.1
```

Our understanding was that the above would say that `@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fs` requires `graphql` (apparently due to the error) and that it would be able to find it.

Is there any alternative ways to handle this?